# Within an array of objects modify all previous objects to an object with a specific property

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I have an array of objects, and according to a property inserted in one of them i would like to mark or select all the objects previous to that object container of the specific property

My array is in this way:

```
const arrX= [
      { status: '1' },
      { status: '2'},
      { status: '3', imHere: true },
      { status: '4' },
    ];
```

Then due to the property `imHere` on arrX[2], the positions arrX[0] and arrX[1] should be modified.

My expected result would be :

```
const arrX= [
      { status: '1',wasHere:true },
      { status: '2',wasHere:true},
      { status: '3', imHere: true },
      { status: '4' },
    ];
```

I know that the `map` method would be quite useful in this case, but can´t find the way to check from index of object containing `imHere` backwards the former positions

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular; I removed the tag. To do this, simply iterate over the array. Add the property as long as `imHere` is undefined. When it is defined, exit the loop. You can also use `Array.findIndex()` to find the index of the imHere element, then iterate over all elements with a smaller index.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use `.findIndex()` and `.map()`:

```js
const arrX= [{ status: '1' }, { status: '2'}, { status: '3', imHere: true }, { status: '4'}];

const imHereIndex = arrX.findIndex(({imHere}) => imHere === true);
const result = arrX.map((val, index) => index < imHereIndex
     ? { ...val, wasHere: true }
     : val
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if @Kinglish answer works like a charm I want to share another way to achieve your goal. This road is surely longer than Kinglish ones, never then less is a good alternative.

```
      { status: '4' },
    ];
    
function findProperty(arr) {
  const hasProperty = arr.findIndex(el => Object.keys(el).includes('imHere'))
  const addNewProperty = arr.map((el,i) => (i < hasProperty) ? {...el, wasHere: true} : el)
  
  return addNewProperty
}

const updatedArray = findProperty(arrX)
console.log(updatedArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method for it using `Array#reduce` and a boolean to track whether we've encountered `inHere`

```js
const arrX = [
  {status: '1'},
  {status: '2'},
  {status: '3',imHere: true},
  {status: '4'},
];

let found = false,
  updated = arrX.reduce((b, a) => {
    found = found || (a.hasOwnProperty('imHere') && a.imHere === true)
    if (!found) a.wasHere = true;
    return b.concat(a);
  }, [])

console.log(updated)
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple loop - breaking out of it when one of the objects contains `imHere`, otherwise adding in a `wasHere` property.

```js
function update(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!arr[i].imHere) {
      arr[i].wasHere = true;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

const arr = [
  { status: '1' },
  { status: '2' },
  { status: '3', imHere: true },
  { status: '4' },
];

console.log(update(arr));
```